# url amigable No mostar nada

Tags: php7, .htaccess

Necesito que solo muestre la url ([www.misitio.com/login](http://www.misitio.com/login)) nada más Sin QueryString.

En .htaccess escribo lo siguiente:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /login? [L,R=301]
RewriteRule index\.php$ /login? [L,R=301]
```

la url es

```
www.misitio.com/pages/index.php?msg=sessionClose&uid=145
```

queda así y asi debe de quedar

```
www.misitio.com/login
```

.htaccess y index.php están en el mismo directorio

el error

```
Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server.

Apache/2.4.46 (Win64) PHP/7.2 Server at wamprojects Port 80
```

No he tocado nada en el codigo de index.php para implementar las url's amigables

Hay que hacer algo más?

Gracias.